# WaitUntilReady() is not working as expected

Tags: telerik, automated-tests

I am using Telerik.Testing.Framework.2012.2.1527
I am using the below code. I am getting null for "findElem" all the time. but when I am in debug mode it is fine. WaitUntilReady(); is not working as expected for me. In my scenario I should not be using waitforelement and specify timeout.

```
   public bool IsPresentbyInputId(string findCondition)
    {
            Manager.ActiveBrowser.WaitUntilReady();
            Element findElem = Manager.ActiveBrowser.Find.ByExpression(new HtmlFindExpression("tagname=input", "id=" + findCondition));
            Manager.ActiveBrowser.WaitUntilReady();
            return findElem != null && !findElem.Attributes.Any(s => s.Value.Contains("display:none"));         
    }
```

Can you let m know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the delay getting back to you on this.

One thing to keep in mind is that WaitUntilReady is monitoring the browsers "Ready" flag. This flag is set as soon as the browser is done the main HTML page (e.g. MyPage.html) plus any referenced resources (images, css files, js files, etc.). It does not take into account any Ajax Postbacks that are initiated as a result of the JavaScript getting control once the page is loaded.

Ajax Postbacks (usually shown visually via a some type of spinning circle as data is being fetched from the web server) can cause the DOM to be modified long after WaitUntilReady returns control to your test code. If setting Execution Delay > 500 makes your test work, it's my bet your application is doing Ajax Postbacks causing the DOM to change.

There are two possible ways to overcome this particular problem:
1) Add a ActiveBrowser.WaitForAjax() call right after the WaitUntilReady() call. This will cause your test to wait until all Ajax connections to your web server are closed.
2) Add a WaitForElement after the WaitUntilReady. For example:
ActiveBrowser.WaitForElement(new HtmlFindExpression("id=maindiv"), 30000, false);
This will cause your code to wait for an element matching the specified properties to exist before moving on.

I hope this helps.

Cody
Test Studio Support Officer